# Make doxygen accept no-documentation for an item (but not ignore it)

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation, code-documentation

When you run doxygen, you often get a lot of:

```
warning: some-thing-or-another is not documented.
```

For some items, you just want to fill in the documentation; but other are too trivial to document, or I just want listing without documentation.

Now, you could suppress these warnings with `///@cond` and `///@endcond`, but then the some-thing-or-another will be yanked out of the documentation, which is not what I wanted.

So, how can I make doxygen not warn me about certain items, while keeping the item in the documentaiton with no additional explanatory text?

Answer (score 1):

A bit diving into the trick box.

Doxygen does have a command `\noop` but this is filtered out so it is not seen as documentation.

There are a number of non printing characters like `&zwj;` and `&nbsp;` so defining something like:

```
/// \file

/** the documented fie
 */
void fie(void);

void fie1(void);

/** &zwj; */
void fie2(void);
```

Will result in a warning for `fie1` but not for `fie` and `fie2`.
The disadvantage is that doxygen thinks that `fie2` is documented and thus creates a detailed section for it.

To overcome the "detailed section" problem one would like to have a command that says the function is documented but doesn't show anything and does not emit warnings about missing things, such a function is currently not present in doxygen.